# How can we add legend's value beside of legend with proper alignment and different color in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

```
.legend(dc.legend().x(0).y(5).itemHeight(5).gap(8).horizontal(1)
        .legendWidth(90).itemWidth(95).legendText(function (d) {
    if (d.name == 'category4') {
        return ' VI>20 ' + " " + " : " + d.data;
    }
    if (d.name == 'category3') {
        return 'VI>10 and <=20 ' + " "  + " : " + d.data;
    }
    if (d.name == 'category2') {
        return 'VI>5 and <=10 ' + " "  + " : " + d.data;
    }
    if (d.name == 'category1') {
        return 'VI<=5 ' + " "  + " : " + d.data;
    };
}));
```

I want to display `d.data` in different color and proper alignment.

Answer (score 3):

I think by proper alignment, you mean right-alignment of the numbers.

In general, dc.js can't anticipate every formatting option anyone would want, so most of the accessors and formatters just generate text. But you can customize it by hooking into events.

Your tools here are the `pretransition` event handler, and `tspan`s within the `text` elements created for the legend.

For example, to split the `name` and `data` and left-align the name but right-align the `data` a bit to the right, you could do:

```
  chart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
      chart.selectAll('.dc-legend-item text')
          .text('')
        .append('tspan')
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', 100)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
          .text(function(d) { return d.data; });
  });
```

You'll just need to adjust the processing of the category names.

I've added this to the [pie external labels](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/pie-external-labels.html) example.